# why isn't it reading the input value in my object?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object, input

I am at the stage in my learning that i am going over some old mini projects and trying to transfer old functional programming to OOP. In this case below i'd imagine its easier to have stayed with a basic funtion based on the simplicity of the project, but i just wanted to change it to OOP so I start getting the hang of the difference between both. The problem I have is when i assign numberBox.value to my years property it reads it as null ( the value when the page is loaded)  despite me having an input onclick event pointing towards the convert function, When i had my basic functional code before hand it read the value of numberBox just fine and changed with every key input as the input Event should. Why doesnt it recognise it in my object?

```js
const numberBox = document.querySelector('#years');
const days = document.querySelector('#days');
const hours = document.querySelector('#hours');
const minutes = document.querySelector('#minutes');

numberBox.addEventListener('input', convert );

let converter =  {

    years: numberBox.value,

    toDays: function () {

        return this.years*365;

    },

    toHours: function () {

        return this.years*8760;

    },

    toMinutes: function () {

        return this.years*525600;

    }

};

function convert () {

    days.lastElementChild.innerHTML = converter.toDays();
    hours.lastElementChild.innerHTML = converter.toHours();
    minutes.lastElementChild.innerHTML = converter.toMinutes();

}
```

below is my old functional code before i changed to OOP. I thought both should work but it seems I am wrong. Thanks All

```js
function convert () {

    let years = numberBox.value; // could also use THIS.value as this is the box i am inputting on 
    
    days.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 365;
    hours.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 8760;
    minutes.lastElementChild.innerHTML = years * 525600;

}
```

Comment: Your new code doesn't update `converter.years` when an input event happens, unlike the old code that creates the `years` variable every time.

Comment: A JS note: don't use `.innerHTML` if you're setting text, use `.textContent`. Developing that habit now means fewer potential code injection exploit bugs later.

Comment: Hey, you are talking to real people here! Please honor them with correctly used capitals and markups.

Answer (score 0):

- `numberBox.value` => `Number(numberBox.value)`. Always convert text values into appropriate type!
- `function convert () {...}` Add into function `converter.years = Number(numberBox.value)`, otherwise you work with `converter.years` property, but never assign it updated value from your input.

Comment: could anyone tell me why i have been marked down for this question ? I have only started learning two months ago , i thought it was a reasonable question. Seems to happen to me a lot ?

Comment: @KevinGreetham They are jealous of how simple your problems are :)

Comment: perhaps so ! haha